# Python update google sheet from local csv problem

Tags: python, csv, google-sheets

I am a beginner in python.
I have successfully put together the script to update my google sheet from some hard coded values

```
Test1 = [["1/1/2020",4000],["4/4/2020",3000],["7/12/2020",'salah4-tiga1000']]
```

But when I try to update from a local csv file,

```
Test2 = pd.read_csv(ordersCSV).to_json()
```

I can see the csv file data running in my terminal, but it is not updating the google sheet.
Can you help me to see what I missed please.
Thank you in advance.

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from oauth2client.transport import request

from pprint import pprint

from numpy import greater
import pandas as pd
from pandas.core import series
from pandas.core.indexes.base import Index
from pyasn1.type.univ import Null


SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'drfruit4.json'
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']

creds = None
creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

SPREADSHEET_ID = '1rpgVUAmLojG1_U2SRQ_x9vQGI16mEYiOCGcZLrIRZOQ'

service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)

# Call the Sheets API
sheet =service.spreadsheets()
result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID,
                            range="Detail_Exp_SiteGiant_via_Python!A1:Z1100").execute()

values = result.get('values',[])

Test1 = [["1/1/2020",4000],["4/4/2020",3000],["7/12/2020",'salah4-tiga1000']]

ordersCSV = r'Ready4Sofia.csv'
Test2 = pd.read_csv(ordersCSV).to_json()

request = sheet.values().update(spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID,
                                range="Detail_Exp_SiteGiant_via_Python!A1", valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED", body={'values':Test2}).execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62917910/python-export-pandas-dataframe-to-google-sheets-solved) .
Thanks to Stack Overflow and all the contributors.