# How can I Export Pandas DataFrame to Google Sheets (specific cell) using Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

- I can read data and write data to a google sheet.
- I can also write a pandas dataframe to a google sheet `cell(1,1)`.

I am now trying to write the same dataframe to a specific cell (like `cell(20,20)`) on a sheet.

resources:

- this link is close, but only refers to the sheet and does not specify the cell: [How can I Export Pandas DataFrame to Google Sheets using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62917910/how-can-i-export-pandas-dataframe-to-google-sheets-using-python)
- the docs are here, but the example seems to only refer to a sheet (so the result is again `cell(1,1)`): https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/user-guide.html#using-gspread-with-pandas

what i have tried:

- i have tried to modify the `update_cell` command with a dataframe.

```py
# this works
sh.sheet1.update_cell(20,20,'hello world')

# but this fails

# example dataframe
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

# write to a specific cell
sh.sheet1.update_cell(20,20,df)
```

So my question is, **how can i specify the cell that the pandas Dataframe is written to ?**

Comment: Try with this `sh.update(cell, df.to_csv(index=False))`

Comment: The second answer to your linked question allows the top-left cell address to be specified; https://stackoverflow.com/a/68951536/53341 pyghseets manual; https://pygsheets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/worksheet.html#pygsheets.Worksheet.set_dataframe

Comment: @Tasos,  this was close, but not quite there.  All the data of the dataframe went into one cell.   So with `sh.update('b20', df.to_csv(index=False))` , the entire df went into cell `b20`...

Comment: That's true. I haven't used it myself, but I was able to find this through github search. A python package called `gspread-dataframe` (https://github.com/robin900/gspread-dataframe) which has the functionality you need. With the `set_with_dataframe` you can specify the dataframe and the cell you want to start with.

Comment: @Tasos,  it was a good starting point nevertheless, so appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the data frame cannot be directly used to `value` of `update_cell(row, col, value)`. [Ref](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v5.7.0/api/models/worksheet.html#gspread.worksheet.Worksheet.update_cell) So, in your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
sh.sheet1.update_cell(20,20,df)
```

#### To:

```
sh.sheet1.update("T20", [df.columns.values.tolist(), *df.values.tolist()], value_input_option="USER_ENTERED")
```

or, if you don't want to include the header row, please test the following modification.

```
sh.sheet1.update("T20", df.values.tolist(), value_input_option="USER_ENTERED")
```

- I thought that `20,20` of `sh.sheet1.update_cell(20,20,df)` is a cell "T20".

#### Note:

- From your showing script, I guessed that you are using [gspread](https://github.com/burnash/gspread).

#### Reference:

- [update(range_name, values=None, **kwargs)](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v5.7.0/api/models/worksheet.html#gspread.worksheet.Worksheet.update)

### Added:

About your following additional question,

> one question: is the user able to replace "t20" with a cell reference (like cell(10,20)) ?

If you want to use the coordinate like `20, 20` as "T20", how about the following modification?

```
sh.sheet1.update(gspread.utils.rowcol_to_a1(20, 20), [df.columns.values.tolist(), *df.values.tolist()], value_input_option="USER_ENTERED")
```

or

```
sh.sheet1.update(gspread.utils.rowcol_to_a1(20, 20), df.values.tolist(), value_input_option="USER_ENTERED")
```

- In this case, `gspread.utils.rowcol_to_a1(20, 20)` is converted to "T20".

#### Reference:

- [gspread.utils.rowcol_to_a1(row, col)](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v5.7.0/api/utils.html#gspread.utils.rowcol_to_a1)

Comment: this is correct, i have used gspread. if there is a better (or official) module please do say so.  .  . Also, i am marking this as the accepted answer as it resolves the.

Comment: one question: is the user able to replace "t20" with a cell reference (like `cell(10,20)`) ?

Comment: @D.L Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your additional question, I added one more modified script. Please confirm it.

Comment: this was the final part and completes the question in full.